# Check if survey was completed in the past 5 minutes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am creating a survey where if it was finished within the past 5 minutes, it should redirect to the results page, but if after 5 minutes, you'd like to redo it again, you can access to the survey again, without redirect.

When clicking the 'Finish' button, it takes you to the beginning of the survey where it outputs this:

```
var surveyprogress_1 = 
    {"survey": { 
    "id": 1, 
    "title": "Find your power animal", 
    "shortname": "poweranimal", 
    "completiondate": "2018-07-25T09:41:41.06Z",  //When it was filled
    "iscomplete": true
}};
```

So to check if it was filled withing the past 5 minutes, I'd need to compare it with the `completiondate`

To eliminate the timezone / comparison issue, I’ve set it so that the date comes out as UTC time.  So, the script converts its local time to UTC before doing any comparisons.

The problem is no matter what I try, I can't get it to work.

Code I tried: https://jsfiddle.net/3otxbemd/15/

It's working there, but not on my survey

Comment: Post the code that you have tried

Comment: I assume you stored the startdate as well. If so, you can simply distract the startdate form the completiondate and check wether it's greater than 300.000ms (5 minutes)

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried to set a timeOut when the user starts to fill the survey. You can use the `setTimeout(check_if_filled(), 300000);` where check_if_filled is a function which is triggered after 5 minutes (300000 miliseconds). It can make a variable true if every field is filled or it can remain false if some fields are empty. When the user press 'Finish' button, it should trigger a function which checks if the variable is true or false and to execute what you need it to do.

Answer (score 0):

The way in witch you are storing `completiondate` is different from the one you are using in the jsfiddle. you should change the regex expression that you are using in the jsfiddle or change the format of time of `completiondate` to be like the one in jsfiddle